# I want to use in oop with protected static

Tags: php, oop, static, protected

I am learning oop.
I try to cover the oop and to understand the idea behind oop.
I have code and i want to use with protect static for an understanding.
I Declare attributes: `protected static $formula` .
And I call to  `protected static $formula` by `self :: $formula = $this->width * $this->height;`.
When I run the code in debuger I got `$formula = null`.
`$formula' should be = 10000.
I don't know why ?
Thanks for any help.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
Class Rectangle {

//Declare the attributes:
public $width = 0;
public $height = 0;
protected static $formula = 0;

//Method to set the dimensions.
Function set_size($w = 0, $h = 0) {
        $this->width = $w;
        $this->height = $h;
        self :: $formula = $this->width * $this->height;
}

//Method to calculate and return the area.
function get_area() {
            $this->set_size(100,100);
    return ($formula);
    }

}

$rect = new Rectangle ();
echo $rect->get_area();
```

?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has a small bug in `get_area`:

```
return ($formula);
```

Should be:

```
return self::$formula;
```